# Build html grid from center in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to programmatically build a grid layout of divs however I'm trying to start from the "center" of the html page placing them in a "spiral" way.

e.g. if i have a grid of divs like

```
123
456
789
```

i need it so that the no 5. div is at 0,0 taking into account that there are varying number of divs and also a varying screen size...the width of the div are all going to be the same

Can someone give me some tips on how to build the logic for this?

Comment: http://runnable.com/UgEReI0UeNUMAAE_/how-to-create-data-grid-using-jquery-ui

Comment: I'd use absolute-positioning and the power of....MATH!

Comment: A spiralled grid? A grid is a grid, and they're usually uniform. Got an image of what you're thinking of?

Comment: I am thinking I need to calculate the area of the divs combined then offset it to the 0,0...but I'm not sure how to accomplish it in javascript.