# Calculate Number Rows and Columns in Area

Tags: javascript, math, grid

I'm trying to create an algorithm logic to display a grid of divs. But how do I determine an as approximate as possible an equal distribution of number of rows and columns to use. Given if I only know the width and height of a grid cell and given a specific number of cells.

Comment: Can you be a bit more explanatory as a) total AREA is unknown. b) total # of columns/ rows is unkown

Comment: Let start with what you know. You know the width and height of each grid cell? Are they all the same? And you want to know how many columns to use based on that?

Comment: Oh, apologies, then I misread.  If you don't know the dimensions of the area to be covered, then there's no way to solve this.

Comment: I know the with and height of each cell? Yes
I know how many columns and rows? No.

Comment: You will need to clarify.  If you are trying to solve `a = b / c` (effectively), but you only know `c`, then there is no way to find `a`.

Comment: Cool well what I'm trying to do is build out a grid from the "center" knowing that the center is 0,0 and each div is going to be same width and height.

Comment: see this post for clarification on what I'm trying to achieve...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20668259/build-html-grid-from-center-in-javascript?noredirect=1#comment30949824_20668259 soorry if I'm breaking any posting rules

Comment: @Kendall: It seems like these questions are effectively duplicates of one another.  Please close/delete one or other of them ;)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a script i wrote some time ago to calculate the grid based on the number of elements to display. i hope this is what you are searching for.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>packing n squares in a rectangle</title>
<style>
html,body{
height:100%;
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
}
#c>div{
 box-sizing:border-box;
 border:1px solid #fff;
 background-color:#C99;
 float:left;
}
#c{
 position:absolute;
}
</style>
<script>
var best_square4=function(w,h,n){
 var s=Math.sqrt(w*h/n)|0;c=w/s|0,r=h/s|0,t=c*r;
 while(t<=n){s--;c=w/s|0;r=h/s|0;t=c*r;}
 c=r==1?n:c;r=Math.ceil(n/c);
 tw=c*s;th=r*s;pl=((w-tw)/2)|0;pt=((h-th)/2)|0;
 return [w,h,s,tw,th,pl,pt];//containerWidth,ContainerHeight,finalSquareSize,finalBoxWidth,finalBoxheight,marginLeft,marginTop
}

var init=function(){
var w=document.body.offsetWidth,h=document.body.offsetHeight,n=(Math.random()*1000>>0)+1,a=best_square4(w,h,n);
var f=document.createDocumentFragment();
for(var i=0;i<n;i++){
 var div=document.createElement('div');
 div.style.cssText='width:'+a[2]+'px;height:'+a[2]+'px;';
 f.appendChild(div);
}
container=document.createElement('div');
container.id='c';
container.style.cssText='padding-left:'+a[5]+'px;padding-top:'+a[6]+'px;width:'+a[3]+'px;height:'+a[4]+'px;';
container.appendChild(f);
document.body.appendChild(container);
}
window.onload=init;
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

**DEMO** (clicking ▶ Run changes to another random number)

http://jsfiddle.net/e7My4/3/

this is a PACKING algorithm i wrote, which uses shorthand and bitwise operators to shorten the code and also has less impact to real world webapplications.

to create a even better display function (init in my case) i suggest to append the cssText as a stylesheet rule, so that you don't have hundreads of `style="width:64px,height:64px"`

```
var rule='#c>div{width:'+a[2]+'px;height:'+a[2]+'px}'
```

**EDIT**

to handle events on so many elements:

http://jsfiddle.net/e7My4/4/

if you have some questions about this code just ask.

Comment: This is pretty grim code.

Comment: what means pretty grim?

Comment: ["grim - uninviting, forbidding"](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/grim).  A bunch of one-letter variable names is very hard to make any sense of.

Comment: Math.sqrt(w*h/n) <- this is the important stuff. which allows you to know one side of a square which will be inside the area.the rest just calculates margins and if the size is really small enough.

Comment: you have some questions about the code?

Comment: No, I'm just saying it's unpleasant to read and difficult to understand.  I would recommend cleaning it up for the purposes of a SO answer ;)

Comment: the purpose of best_square4 function is to copy and past.it calculates all you need to pack elements inside element using as much possible space.As all variables are private there is no need for long names.not to talk about the slowdown impact it would have on the function.Also starting to explain shorthand functions and bitwise operators would be a to long answer.i'm just trying to help ppl here.

Comment: "if you have some questions about this code just ask." <- if you don't understand that part of my answer and you have no questions pls explain your downvote.

Comment: I think I already have...